# Set Bold to a Paragraph in GemBox Document ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gembox-document

I am using GemBox.Document library in my ASP.Net Page. I have a paragraph which contains line breaks and I also need to set the paragraph to bold.
I my below code the variable str contains line break characters.

TRY 1
Line breaks work well in the below code
`var p3 = new Paragraph(wDoc, str);`
How to set BOLD to this paragraph

TRY 2
Bold work well in the below code

```
    var p3 = new Paragraph(wDoc, 
        new Run(wDoc, str) { CharacterFormat = { Bold = true } }
   );
```

This doesn't allow line breaks

Please help for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is something like this:

```cs
var paragraph = new Paragraph(wDoc);
paragraph.Content.LoadText(str, new CharacterFormat() { Bold = true });
```

Or this:

```cs
var paragraph = new Paragraph(wDoc);
paragraph.CharacterFormatForParagraphMark.Bold = true;
paragraph.Content.LoadText(str);
```

But just in case you're interested, the thing to note here is that line breaks are represented with `SpecialCharacter` objects, not with `Run` objects.

So the following would be the "manual" way in which you would need to handle those breaks yourself, you would need to add the correct elements to the `Paragraph.Inlines` collection:

```cs
string str = "Sample 1\nSample 2\nSample 3";
string[] strLines = str.Split('\n');

var paragraph = new Paragraph(wDoc);

for (int i = 0; i < strLines.Length; i++)
{
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(
        new Run(wDoc, strLines[i]) { CharacterFormat = { Bold = true } });

    if (i != strLines.Length - 1)
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(
            new SpecialCharacter(wDoc, SpecialCharacterType.LineBreak));
}
```

That is the same as if you were using this `Paragraph` constructor:

```cs
var paragraph = new Paragraph(wDoc,
    new Run(wDoc, "Sample 1") { CharacterFormat = { Bold = true } },
    new SpecialCharacter(wDoc, SpecialCharacterType.LineBreak),
    new Run(wDoc, "Sample 2") { CharacterFormat = { Bold = true } },
    new SpecialCharacter(wDoc, SpecialCharacterType.LineBreak),
    new Run(wDoc, "Sample 3") { CharacterFormat = { Bold = true } });
```

Comment: I tried the first one, as it suits my requirement. It works fine. Thanks Mario

Comment: @Maddy great! Let me know if you need anything else. Also, don't forget to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Hi Mario. Sorry I don't know about accept an answer. Hereafter I will make it. Thanks for your support. I am on the project. I will update